# Reply to email without opening a new window

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is there any way I can reply to emails from within the main window? That is, something like turning the bottom-right panel into a text editing area, instead of opening the compose window.

It's perhaps just a personal foible, but I find it both slow and mentally jarring to be constantly moving in and out of the main context -- especially when I'm ploughing through emails writing one-line replies.

Alternatively, is there any other mail client which handles this better? I've tried evolution and claws, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Thunderbird Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/) add-on has an inline reply feature.